# Eclipse installer gives proxy error on Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, proxy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hr7W.png)

As I try to install Eclipse IDE on MAC OS X, It gives me a proxy error and fails. Don't know what to change

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No I don't think so

Comment: I found another Eclipse version (Mars) which does not run into this problem. I had the problem with Neon